# How to mimic upload_to function in models with ordinary form

Tags: python, django

Hi I'm having this models, forms, views, settings let say

models.py

```
class ProfileModel(models.Model):
   user = Foreignkey(get_user_model()...) 
   first_name = forms.CharField(....) # some attrs
   photo = models.ImageField(uploads_to='uploads/%Y/%m/%d', ...)
```

forms.py

```
class ProfileForm(forms.Form):
   first_name = forms.CharField()
   photo = forms.ImageField()

   def handle(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
       data = self.cleaned_data
       # update the profile model
       Profile.objects.filter(user__exact=request.user).update(**data)
```

views.py

```
def update_profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
       form = forms.ProfileForm(request.DATA, request.FILES)
       if form.is_valid():
          # update here via handle of form
          form.handle(request, *args, **kwargs)
       else:
          #... something
```

settings.py

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

The idea here is just use a form to update a model (not a modelform).

via admin, upload_to seems to work
e.g upload a picture, url = /media/uploads/..../photo

when its comes to my form it just recognizes /media/ but not the upload_to, [btw its working its just that its behavior] 
e.g upload a picture, url = /media/photo

it seems its not triggering the upload_to,

I know the benefit of the modelform but in this case, is there a way?

Answer (score 0):

```
def comment_update(request,pk):
context ={} 
comment = get_object_or_404(Comment,pk=pk)
post_pk = comment.post.pk
form = CommentForm(request.POST or None, instance = comment)
if request.user == comment_user:
    if form.is_valid(): 
        form.save() 
        return redirect('src:detail',pk=post_pk)
context["form"] = form 
return render(request, "comment_form.html", context)
```

Comment is model name
This way is easily update existing data.
pk is primary key.

Comment: i believe form.save() is a modelform method? ye its my bad, it should be request.POST. tho please consider it as an example

Comment: ah i see, I just search the instance=... its making the form as an instance of a model.

Answer (score 0):

Shah Vipul, answer was good.

But considering the code above,

its a bizzare one in which update() does not recognize the upload_to

What i do here was.

forms.py [my bad it should be ProfileModel not Profile] anyway.

```
...
def handle(...):
    user = request.user
    photo = self.clean_data.pop('photo')

    ProfileModel.objects.filter(user__exact=user).update(**data)
    user.profile.photo = photo
    user.profile.save(update_fields=['photo',])
```

seems to work, but if someone can explain why is that?